# Grab curl output's cookie in bash script

Tags: bash, curl, cookies

When I send a curl command in my bash shell script I get output as follows

```
< Date: Fri, 14 Jul 2017 10:21:25 GMT
< Set-Cookie: vmware-api-session-id=7ed7b5e95530fd95c1a6d71cf91f7140;Path=/rest;Secure;HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
```

How an I access `vmware-api-session-id` going ahead. Should I store it in a variable while executing curl?

Comment: You want the string `7ed7b5e95530fd95c1a6d71cf91f7140` stored in a variable?

Answer (score -1):

You can execute the following command:

```
sessionid=`[YOUR CURL COMMAND] 2>&1 | grep -o vmware-api-session-id=[0-9a-z]+ | grep -o [0-9a-z]+`
```

`2>&1` sends stderr to stdout. You need this, because curl sends session-information to stderr.

Using your example values, this would translate into

```
sessionid=7ed7b5e95530fd95c1a6d71cf91f7140
```

Now you can access the cookie value by adressing the variable `${sessionid}`

If you want to export the vairable, you can use:

```
sessionid=`[YOUR CURL COMMAND] 2>&1 | grep -o vmware-api-session-id=[0-9a-z]+ | grep -o [0-9a-z]+`
export sessionid
```

or shorter

```
export sessionid=`[YOUR CURL COMMAND] 2>&1 | grep -o vmware-api-session-id=[0-9a-z]+ | grep -o [0-9a-z]+`
```

Comment: This gave me `api-session-id` stored in `vmware-api-session-id` variable

Comment: @love2code You're right! I forgot to put -o in the grep command. Also I had to rename the variable. I fixed it and edited my original post!

Comment: This gives blank output when I do `echo $sessionid` / `echo ${sessionid}`

Comment: @love2code Of course! Curl sends sessioninformation to stderr insted of stdout. Another edit and now it should run!

Comment: Still blank output !!

Comment: Can you give me an example of your curl command, so I can debug and try it myself?

Comment: I am trying vmware API `export sessionid=\`curl -kv -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' --basic -u user:password $VCENTER/rest/com/vmware/cis/session 2>&1| grep -o vmware-api-session-id=[0-9a-z]+ | grep -o [0-9a-z]+\` `

Comment: Can you please post the output of `curl -kv -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' --basic -u user:password $VCENTER/rest/com/vmware/cis/session 2>&1`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149355/discussion-between-love2code-and-lukas-isselbacher).